# flutter : willpopscope, The return type 'future<bool?>' isn't 'future<bool>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made changes in the method as you can see below while calling it I am not sure how to fix it. The issue is being caused after I upgraded and trying to solve all the non-nullable or ``null-safety```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()=> showDialog<bool>(context: context,
          builder: (context)=> AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Alert'),
            content: Text('Voulez vous quitter l\'application ?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(onPressed:(){
                if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                  exit(0);
                }
              },
                  child: Text('Oui')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                  child: Text('Non')
              )
            ],
          )
      ),
          child: Scaffold()
}
```

here is the error error: The return type 'Future' isn't a 'Future', as required by the closure's context.

how can i fix this ?

Comment: try changing `onWillPop: ()=> ` to `onWillPop: () async =>`

Comment: i did that . No thing changed

Comment: It seems your problem related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67184531/flutter-willpopscope-with-alertdialog-migration-to-null-safety

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter WillPopScope with AlertDialog migration to null-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67184531/flutter-willpopscope-with-alertdialog-migration-to-null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is that `showDialog` function can return a `null` value, when e.g. user closes the dialog by clicking on its background. And in the same time, `onWillPopScope` require a  non-nullable boolean.
(In both cases we're talking about Futures returning nullable or not booleans to be precise, but that's not the problem here)

So the solution is to return not a a `showDialog` result, but simply the `showDialog` result compared to `true`, so that `null` would change into `false`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()=> showDialog<bool>(context: context,
          builder: (context)=> AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Alert'),
            content: Text('Voulez vous quitter l\'application ?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(onPressed:(){
                if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                  exit(0);
                }
              },
                  child: Text('Oui')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                  child: Text('Non')
              )
            ],
          )
      ) == true,
          child: Scaffold()
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested the code, but it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Try this let me know if it works for you

```
 Future<bool> _onClose() async {
    return await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Alert'),
              content: Text('Voulez vous quitter l\'application ?'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                        SystemNavigator.pop();
                      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                        exit(0);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Oui')),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                    child: Text('Non'))
              ],
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onClose,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```